# groovy words count per file and return boolen

Tags: file, groovy

I'm little stack. I'm try count per file words like `END` and `BEGIN`. If i find in fille one of them return true else false. Word in first if with `BEGIN` works ok, but it don't return boolen. Secend if with `END` don't work. Why ? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

```
import groovy.io.FileType

def splitStatements() {

    def wordCount_END = 0
    def wordCount_BEGIN = 0
    def dir = new File("C:\\Groovy\\Files")

    dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
   Scanner s = new Scanner(file) 
   while (s.hasNext()) {
       if (s.next().equals('BEGIN')){ 
           wordCount_BEGIN++
       }else if (s.next().equals('END')){
           wordCount_END++                              
       }

        if (wordCount_END == 0 && wordCount_BEGIN == 0){
            //how return "false"

        }else if (wordCount_END != 0 && wordCount_BEGIN != 0){
            //how return "true"

        }             
    }
        println wordCount_END
        println wordCount_BEGIN                           
    }                         
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `"true"` is a String, and `true` is Boolean
2. `dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file -> return "true" }` will exit from current cycle of `eachFileRecurse` anf not from the method `splitStatements`
3. something wrong with your algorithm. if you want to count `BEGIN` & `END` words in files why you try to return after finding the first one?

Comment: So, 1. It can be a string because i want to take that return to put in XML, so that is ok for me. 3. I need to take return each file true or false.

Comment: I edit my algorithm, it count now right but, how return true or false from secend if ? It can be string or Boolen

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you need to find for each file which word was first( begin or end) ?

Comment: Nop, I want to count in every file how many is there END and BEGIN. If more then 1(END or BEGIN) return true as string. and in result want from each file return true or false :)

Comment: `eachFileRecurse` return void, how return string from this if ?